# Getting share link of a word doccument downloaded from drive

Tags: python, metadata, drive

I am programming a file organizer in python, so i have a bunch of word documents that were downloaded from google drive, i need the sharelink of drive from this documents so my question is if there is a way to get this sharelink from the metadata of the document.

Comment: you might want to use google drive api --> https://developers.google.com/drive

Comment: is just that the organizer is supposed to be used offline, but if there isn´t a way to do what i want i will be forced to do that. thanks